# Access Wordpress User data to login/register through App REST

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a mobile application using Ionic Framework for my E-commerce website developed using Woocommerce.

I need to use a single database for the users, so that the registered users can access their profiles and non-registered users can register to the website / app simultaneously with the same credentials.

I found this awesome [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/) which claims to provide with REST User data to help login/register but I am unable to use this as I am already using Reactor Core and WP-API to access my products data and WordPress wouldn't allow me to use all these plugins simultaneously.

Comment: I think this question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360310/wordpress-json-api-and-ajax-login)

Answer (score 2):

Well WordPress it self has a communication protocol which is XML-RPC you can read more on it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API), However it does not have authentication method builtin.

But you can try it some thing like this:

```
function mynamespace_getUserID( $args ) {
    global $wp_xmlrpc_server;
    $wp_xmlrpc_server->escape( $args );

    $blog_id  = $args[0];
    $username = $args[1];
    $password = $args[2];

    if ( ! $user = $wp_xmlrpc_server->login( $username, $password ) )
        return $wp_xmlrpc_server->error;

    return $user->ID;    
}

function mynamespace_new_xmlrpc_methods( $methods ) {
    $methods['mynamespace.getUserID'] = 'mynamespace_getUserID';
    return $methods;   
}
add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'mynamespace_new_xmlrpc_methods');
```

You can read more on Extending XML-RPC [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending). If you are using client side language for authentication, then you can check [WordPress XmlRpc Javascript Api](https://github.com/developerworks/wordpress-xmlrpc-javascript-api)