# wordpress json api and ajax login

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress theme based on AngularJS framework, I already setup WP REST API and it is accessible from the /wp-json, My login form is ajax driven (AngularJS controller) now I am looking for a way to authenticate my users against wordpress back-end, I searched all over docs, it says cookie authentication is applicable in this case. it also talks of sending "nonce" for each parameter but there is no clue on how to send username/password for first time authentication from within ajax request. Does json rest api support sending username/password ? it seems there is no routes to it.

I think i am missing something fundamental/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of authentication are the here is the document for the authentication.

> http://wp-api.org/guides/authentication.html

You need to login using basic authentication method then wordpress will automatically set the cookies for the login user and you need not manage the cookie in your end.

> **PHP Client** https://github.com/WP-API/client-php
>
> **JS CLient** https://github.com/WP-API/client-js

Comment: thanks for answering, seems like its not working for me, it works from curl but then i have to send the u/p with every request, in an ajax request it always gives me authorization error  401, i encoded the username:password with base64

Comment: Please try with this http://wp-api.org/guides/getting-started.html#editing-and-creating-posts

Comment: I am trying that, but i have a small question: suppose if i login with a regular wordpress login form at /wp-login.php and after successful login is is possible to access this pages like /wp-json/users/me, unfortunately it gives me 401 error no matter i am logged in or not

Comment: No you can not use that. You need to pass username and password in each request. I have added on client which used for the to call api.

Comment: sorry but sending username/password in each request will not be viable in my website, it will also overload the request by checking for user credentials each time, I was used to jquery and it worked just like simple PHP websites, feels like this whole thing of json-api is complicating simple tasks which was done earlier with couple of lines of code.

Comment: I have added JS client link it will help with angular js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93453/discussion-between-abhishek-k-and-mitul).